# h:commandButton is execute before click

Tags: jsf, jstl

I'm use jsf 2.2 with tomcat.
I'm trying to build a shopping cart, i have an xhtml page that add product to the cart,
The problem is that the action in h:commandButton is called every time i refresh the page or if I'm Entering the page for the first time.

for example i have 3 product in my data base, and if i refresh the page without click -
add to cart button, all three products is added to the cart - even they shouldn't.

i want the action to preform only if i click the button...any idea how to solve it?

that my necklaces.xhtml - in this page, the action in this line is called every time i click refresh:

```
    <h:commandButton class="btn btn-success" immediate="true" id="AddToCart" value="add to cart" action="#{shoppingCartController.orderNecklace(p)}"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="homeStyle.css" library="css" />      
        <h:outputScript name="homeJS.js" library="js" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
                         
        <title>necklaces</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
       <div class="main-div">
         <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                <a href="homePage.xhtml" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="#news">Sales</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Categories
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="necklaces.xhtml">necklaces</a>
                        <a href="#">bracelets</a>
                        <a href="#">rings</a>
                        <a href="#">earrings</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <h:outputLink rendered="#{userLogIn1.logged == false}" value="index.xhtml">Login</h:outputLink>
                <a href="cart.xhtml">Cart</a>
                <h:outputLink rendered="#{userLogIn1.logged != false}" value="logOut.xhtml">Logout</h:outputLink>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </div>
      
      <div class="sec1">   
            <hr></hr>
            <h2>Necklaces</h2>
            <hr></hr>
        </div>  
      <div class="wrapper">
      
            <div class = "row container-fluid">
            <c:forEach items="#{productController.findAll()}" var="p" >

                <div class="col-lg-4 product">
                    <h:graphicImage value="#{p.imgPath}" height="150" width="150"/>
                    <br></br>
                    <h:outputText value=" #{p.description}"/>
                    <br></br>
                    <h:outputText value="₪ #{p.price}"/>
                    <h:form>
                    <!-- <h:commandButton class="btn btn-success" id="AddToCart" value="add to cart" action="#{shoppingCartController.orderNecklace(p)}" /> --> 
                    <h:commandButton class="btn btn-success" immediate="true" id="AddToCart" value="add to cart" action="#{shoppingCartController.orderNecklace(p)}"/>
                    </h:form>   
                </div>       
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
      </div>
        
   </div>
 </h:body>      
    
</html>
```

that my shoppingCartController.jave, this class adding products to the cart.

```
    package controller;
    
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
    
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    
    import com.ManageBean.userLogIn1;
    
    import entities.Item;
    import entities.Product;
    
    
    @ManagedBean(name="shoppingCartController")
    @SessionScoped
    public class ShoppingCartController implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private List<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
    
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{userLogIn1}")

    private userLogIn1 currentUser;
    
    public String orderNecklace(Product n){
        
        for(int i=0;i<cart.size();i++){
            if(cart.get(i).getProduct().getModelNumber() == n.getModelNumber()){
                cart.get(i).setQuantity(cart.get(i).getQuantity()+1);
                return "cart";
            }
            
        }
        Item temp = new Item(n,currentUser.getName(),1);
        this.cart.add(temp);
        System.out.println("heeeeereee"+ n.getPrice()+"name is: "+currentUser.getName());
        return "cart";
    }

    public List<Item> getCart() {
        return cart;
    }

    public void setCart(List<Item> cart) {
        this.cart = cart;
    }

    public userLogIn1 getCurrentUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }

    public void setCurrentUser(userLogIn1 currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }
  }
```

this is the cart.xhtml page which showing the products in the cart:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="homeStyle.css" library="css" />      
        <h:outputScript name="homeJS.js" library="js" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
                         
        <title>cart</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
       
      <div class="sec1">   
            <hr></hr>
            <h2>Cart</h2>
            <hr></hr>
        </div>  
      <div class="wrapper">
          <h:form>
                <h:dataTable  value="#{shoppingCartController.cart}" var="item" rowClasses="oddRows,evenRows" headerClass="header"
                              styleClass="table" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header" >Model number</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.product.modelNumber}"/>
                    </h:column> 
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header" >Quantity</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.quantity}"/>
                    </h:column>   
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header" >Img</f:facet>
                        <h:graphicImage value="#{item.product.imgPath}" height="100" width="100"/>
                    </h:column> 
                     <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header" >Price</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.product.price}"/>
                    </h:column> 
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header" >Sub Total</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.product.price * item.quantity}"/>
                    </h:column>  
                </h:dataTable>
            </h:form>   
      </div>   
   </div>
 </h:body>        
</html>
```